# What is an intuitive way to understand Cayley's formula?

Tags: graph-theory, intuition

Is there any intuition behind Cayley's formula $n^{n-2}$ for the number of spanning trees of a graph?

Comment: the [number of spanning tress of a complete graph with $n$ vertices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%27s_formula). and you'd like to know the intuition behind the different proofs ? this one seems to be the most "intuitive" : [Double_counting_(proof_technique)#Counting_trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_counting_(proof_technique)#Counting_trees)

Comment: @user2683246: Draw a $K_4$ and find all its spanning trees.